# Table Field Row ID?

Tags: templating, table-field

I need a unique id for each table row.  Something like this which does not work:

`{% for row in block.buttons %}{{ row.id }}{% endfor %}`

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible using the [Twig Loop variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable). The following will add the current iteration of the loop.

```
{% for row in block.buttons %}
    {{ loop.index }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: Beware that `index` starts at 1. If you need 0-indexed, use `index0`.